# Which foo template will be instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, sfinae, template-argument-deduction

Given this code:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<char ...Cs>
auto foo() -> typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Cs) > 1)>::type{
}

template<char C>
void foo() {
}

int main(){
    foo<'s'>();
}
```

I have the above c++ program and I'm just wondering, according rules laid out in the standard, which one of the two "foo" templates will be instantiated for the "foo" call in main.

Comment: It doesn't print anything ... ?

Comment: Have you tried running it? Also, there are no obvious `print` functions....

Comment: Its been a long day. I meant which foo should be called.

Comment: None of them. Because you are not calling anything.

Comment: You should look at SFINAE. First template is disable when `sizeof...(Cs) < 2` as in your case.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open.  The question clearly asks what the STANDARD says, not what someone's compiler says (which may be wrong).  And it's a very useful question about variadic templates and how to terminate them properly.

Comment: @KazDragon It's neither. It's a simple demonstration of SFINAE and as the question is unclear whether the result was unexpected or not, it's unclear whether a simple standard-reference to the SFINAE rule would satisfy it. In any case, "how is SFINAE specified" is a very general question which isn't really how this is phrased.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a print to each one to find out:

```
template<char ...Cs>
auto foo() -> typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Cs) > 1)>::type{
    cout << "1" << endl;
}
template<char C>
void foo() {
    cout << "2" << endl;
}
void EnableIfWithSizeof(){
    foo<'s'>();
}

int main() {
EnableIfWithSizeof();
return 0;
}
```

The resultant output is `2`

Comment: Yes I know. Question is which rule in the standard dictates this.

Comment: Yeah, i am trying to figure that out.

Comment: This looks similar to the [cppreference example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). Since `sizeof...(Cs)>1` is false, `::type` there is a substitution failure, so that line is not considered.